# How to marshal xml in Go but ignore empty fields

Tags: go

If I have a struct which I want to be able to Marhsal/Unmarshal things in and out of xml with (using encoding/xml) - how can I **not** print attributes which are empty?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type MyThing struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"body"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    Street  string   `xml:"street,attr"`
}

func main() {
    var thing *MyThing = &MyThing{Name: "Canister"}
    result, _ := xml.Marshal(thing)
    fmt.Println(string(result))
}
```

For example see http://play.golang.org/p/K9zFsuL1Cw

In the above playground I'd not want to write out my empty *street* attribute; how could I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `omitempty` flag on `street` field.

From [Go XML package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal):

> - a field with a tag including the "omitempty" option is omitted
>     if the field value is empty. The empty values are false, 0, any
>     nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or
>     string of length zero.

In case of your example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type MyThing struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"body"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    Street  string   `xml:"street,attr,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var thing *MyThing = &MyThing{Name: "Canister"}
    result, _ := xml.Marshal(thing)
    fmt.Println(string(result))
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/43fOHP0geJ)</kbd>